# SQL Server type casting behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, type-conversion, string-concatenation

How does SQL Server behave when using `+` operator? It is used to sum the integers and concatenate string as well

Why

```
select '1' + 2 + '33';
```

returns a result of 36, while this

```
select '1' + '33' + 2;
```

results in 135?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server will do automatic implicit conversions as it sees necessary. Since `int` has a higher datatype precedence than `varchar`, when SQL Server seems an `+` applied to a string and an int, it will convert the string to an int first, then apply the `+` operator.

In your first select, it seems `'1'` as a string, and `2` as an int, and therefore, it casts the `'1'` to an int and sums the two, resulting in the value 3. To this, the `'33'` - again converted to an `int` - is added, resulting in the end result of 36.

In your second case, the first `+` is applied to **two strings**, thus resulting in string concatenation and a result of `'133'`. Adding an `int` of 2 causes this string to be turned into an `int`, and thus the end result is 135.

See the invaluable MSDN documentation on [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) to learn all the details of type precedence.